# Express in set notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm really struggling here in writing the set notation & 
I don't know how to begin

[image]

Comment: What symbols of set notation do you know?

Answer (score 3):

The set is simply all the self employed people who are not in goverment sector jobs, so $$B\cap A^c$$ also written as $$B\setminus A$$

Comment: You beat me to it, but my internet connection is so slow that it would not show your answer until a minute after you post it.

Answer (score 1):

Step by step:

1) The set given is a subset of $B$.

2) It has everything of $B$, except the part which intersects $A$.

3) Hence, it is *precisely* the part of $B$ which does not intersect $A$.

4) Hence, it is *precisely* the part of $B$ which intersects the complement of $A$, or $B \cap A^C$.

Comment: has it need to be written in terms of C also?

Comment: No, if you notice this set has nothing to do with $C$, other than the fact that it shares some part  with $C$.